# How to stop getting input from user

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I want to create a string ArrayList with input coming from user but inputs going to endless. How to stop it when user want.

```
public class SortingString {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    System.out.println("Enter the words:");

    while (in.hasNext()) {
        words.add(in.nextLine());
    }

    Collections.sort(words);
}
```

Edit: Thanks for all answers guys. It's working now.

Comment: One option: Define a stop word input, e.g. `STOP`, which, when entered, will cause the loop to stop executing.

Comment: You need to add an 'exit' possibility. For example if the user types "/exit" the application will stop.

Comment: Check whether input string is empty to stop the loop

Comment: `if (words.contains("stop")) break;`

Comment: Another option (that may be preferable in your case?): let the user specify the number of words he/she's going to input

Comment: yeah, you can choose a few string and use it to break loop like "stop", "quit" or "exit"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about?

```
public class SortingString {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

        while (in.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("Enter the word:");
            words.add(in.nextLine());
            System.out.println("Do you want to continue? (y/n)");
            in.hasNext();
            if (!in.nextLine().equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
                break;
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(words);

        in.close(); // Don't forget to close the stream !!
    }
}
```

A more elegant way: (EDIT Posted full code)

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    System.out.println("Enter the words or write STOP to exit:");
    while (in.hasNext()) {
        String inputLine = in.nextLine();
        if (inputLine.equalsIgnoreCase("STOP")) {
            break;
        }
        words.add(inputLine);
    }

    Collections.sort(words);

    System.out.println("The words sorted:");
    System.out.println(words);

    in.close(); // Don't forget to close the stream !!
}
```

Comment: That would be pretty annoying for the user to have to answer after every input word

Comment: @Nadir  added an alternate solution

Comment: @Emax maybe you forgot to add the `inputLine` to the `words` list?

Comment: @Emax no problem :) In general I don't like break statements inside loops, because they can lead to unexpected behaviour for other developers. If they don't read the whole code inside the loop.

Comment: It's a good one but ArrayList is not sorting when I write STOP. Code is totally stop. Where I am a making mistake.

Comment: @miracdogan Are you printing it?

Comment: @miracdogan I posted the full working code, maybe you missed something?

Comment: @Emax Thanks it's working. Sorry I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

This would be a possible solution, where the "quit" word is not added to the `words` list.

```
public class SortingString {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    System.out.println("Enter the words:");
    boolean isFinished = false;
    while (!isFinished && in.hasNext()) {
        String word = in.nextLine();

        if ("q".equals(word)) {
            isFinished = true;
        } else {
            words.add(word);
        }
    }

    in.close(); 
    Collections.sort(words);
}
```